# Calculate the duration in the same column between 2 rows that they are match to each other in another 2 columns using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` as below (for example only show 4 rows, but the `dataframe` have more than thousand over rows):

```
id  location    plateno serialno    type    from/arrive

755 A   ade2384 TA144   11014   2018-01-02 10:13:00

762 A   ax395   TB543   11014   2018-01-02 10:43:00

920 C   ax395   TB543   11000   2018-01-03 09:06:00

976 B   ade2384 TA144   11000   2018-01-03 11:39:00
```

I would like to get the duration(from/arrive) between id 755 (location A) to 976 (location C) (which the plateno & serialno need to be same) and so on, then create a new columns of the duration according to the plateno.

Problem I facing is, I am not sure how to do the calculation using python when there is the need of some requirement then follow by the calculation between the 2 rows.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) The `serialno` for `id` 755 and 976 aren't identical, but your question suggests they should be. Is this an error in the data or a misunderstanding from the question? 2) Will there then be a third example for `plateno` TA144 with a third address, so the method needs to potentially create multiple rows for each `plateno` in the final column?

Comment: Thanks for the questions.
Let me clarify on the questions: 1) They are identical, just the arrangement of the dataframe showing here is out of allignment. So sorry for this as I am not so familiar with the editing here, have the help of a user to edit it before. 2) There will no third address of the plateno ade2384 (TA144 will be the serial no). Each transaction will complete with 2 records. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have one destination and one starting point for each of your `plateno, serialno`. You can use min and max by `plateno, serialno` and then take the difference.

```
df['from/arrive'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from/arrive'])
df = df.groupby(['plateno', 'serialno']).agg({'from/arrive' :['min', 'max']})
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df = df.reset_index()
df['diff'] = df['max'] - df['min']
```

Alternatively, you can use `type` as well in your data

Comment: Thanks Aritesh! That the answer I look for! I been thinking how to solve it. As I not really good in using groupby + .agg. Thank you very much :)